# Draw line charts. Moving from JpGraph to Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, jpgraph

I've an application that based on some values from different inputs (temperature, humidity...), show different charts.
So far I've done that with JpGraph, and I found it pretty easy to do.  You can add a legend easily, and plot as many functions as you want.  You can also fix the scale easily.  Regardless of that, I would like to have some interactivity with the user (I just want that one the user clicks on a point of the graph, the X and Y value are shown).  That is not easy to do with JpGraph because it is just a PNG image.

I was recommended to use Raphael JS library, and I've been reading to the documentation ([Raphael JS Reference](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html)), but I don't see that what I want to do (line charts) is that simple.

So, I am asking, to both Jpgraph users and Raphael JS users if they had had experience with this, and if there is any good tutorial online (I have not able to find one that works with line charts).  The kind of graphs I'm drawing now are like this: [JpGraph Example](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http://www.webtaller.com/images/lecciones/creacion_de_graficas_en_php_con_jpgraph_1.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.webtaller.com/codigo/Clicks.php/944/lenguajes/&usg=__Bculvg9zlEjB4ULhvvmBrkXYxR4=&h=250&w=450&sz=7&hl=en&start=0&sig2=swNn-PjUB416itiAtHVMWw&zoom=1&tbnid=ed_03AjbCVONiM%3a&tbnh=112&tbnw=201&ei=c7WATdmrE82hOoyk-cAI&prev=/images?q=jpgraph&um=1&hl=en&client=ubuntu&sa=N&pwst=1&channel=fs&biw=1280&bih=799&tbs=isch:1&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=553&vpy=442&dur=2372&hovh=167&hovw=301&tx=181&ty=64&oei=c7WATdmrE82hOoyk-cAI&page=1&ndsp=20&ved=1t:429,r:12,s:0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some other options:

- [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/) (SVG)
- [JSXGraph](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/) (SVG and VML for IE)
- [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) (SVG)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [chart plugin](http://g.raphaeljs.com/) for Raphael.  It supports [line charts](http://g.raphaeljs.com/linechart.html).  The [documentation](http://g.raphaeljs.com/reference.html) is certainly lacking - but there is always the [source](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/g.raphael/blob/master/g.line.js).

Answer (score 1):

Answering myself.  After doing some research, I found this one pretty interesting for doing line charts:[Grafico](http://grafico.kilianvalkhof.com/documentation/index.html)